# Will Emf induce in current carrying conductor in solenoid?

Tags: electromagnetic-induction

If a current carrying conductor is placed inside a solenoid where current passes through both solenoid & conductor, Will an extra emf(potential difference)/current  induce in the conductor? [current in conductor is less than that of solenoid]?
Let emf already existing in conductor be E1.

If emf is induced:
Assume emf induced by solenoid to be E2.
Will the emf induced be E1+E2 or E2 or any other value?
Please answer soon...

Comment: Didn't you say the emf induced by the solenoid is $E_1$?  So the emf induced would be $E_1$.  Your question is not very clear.

Comment: The ques. is will emf E2 be generated by the solenoid on conductor (acco. to latest change made in ques.)        Thanks for your response.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Yes. If you place a current carrying conductor in the vicinity of a loop (here solenoid), the magnetic flux passing through the loop will change(because earlier the current carrying conductor was not around) inducing an emf in the loop.

The emf induced $E_1$ can be calculated using [Faraday's law](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Faraday%27s_law_of_induction) and its value, in general, may be either positive or negative depending on the direction of the magnetic field that the current carrying conductor brings with it.

If the previous value of emf in the loop (solenoid) was $E_2$, and the induced emf is $E_1$, the new emf would be $E_2 + E_1$ where $E_1$ may be either positive or negative as mentioned.

Comment: Will new emf depend on angle at which conductor is placed in solenoid

Comment: Yes, of course, because changing the angle of the conductor changes the magnetic field produced by it.

Answer (score 0):

Yes, the emf will add on due to mutual inductance.
When a steady current flows in one coil as in the left illustration, a magnetic field is produced in the other coil. But since that magnetic field is not changing, Faraday's lawtells us that there will be no induced voltage in the secondary coil. But if the switch is opened to stop the current as in the middle illustration, there will be a change in magnetic field in the right hand coil and a voltage will be induced. A coil is a reactionary device, not liking any change! The induced voltage will cause a current to flow in the secondary coil which tries to maintain the magnetic field which was there. The fact that the induced field always opposes the change is an example of Lenz' law. Once the current is interrupted and the switch is closed to cause the current to flow again as in the right hand example, an induced current in the opposite direction will oppose that buildup of magnetic field. This persistent generation of voltages which oppose the change in magnetic field is the operating principle of a transformer. The fact that a change in the current of one coil affects the current and voltage in the second coil is quantified in the property called mutual inductance.

Comment: Could you expand you answer?

Comment: @ZeroTheHero I edited it